# What is static <T> List<T> methodName (List<? super T> input)

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code but i am confused with all the generics.

```
public static <T> List<T> backwards (List<? super T> input) {  
       List<T> output = new ArrayList<T>();  
       return output;  
}
```

My understanding is that I have a public method named `backwards` which creates an arraylist implementing the List interface and returning the arraylist. My question is what actually I am saying to the compiler with the following part......

```
static <T> List<T> backwards (List<? super T> input)
```

Comment: `backwards` takes in a list of some *type*, where that *type* is a supertype of `T` (for example, the input could be a `List<Object>`), and returns a list of `T`.

Comment: Thanks Mehrdad for explaining this.

Comment: Is `input` will be used in `backwards`? I didn't see where it will used.

Answer (score 47):

You are saying to the compiler:

```
<T>
```

"I'm declaring an arbitrary type `T` for this method, which can be anything (non-primitive) for each call of the method."

```
List<T>
```

"This method will return a `List` containing elements of that type `T`."

```
List<? super T> input
```

"This method will take a parameter called `input`, which is a `List` containing elements of type `T`, or any super-type of `T`. For example, if `T` is `Integer`, `input` could be a `List<Integer>`, `List<Number>`, or `List<Object>`."

Comment: This doesn't address what the method signature `public static <T> List<T>` means compared to `public static List<T>`.

Comment: @agarrett `public static List<T>` doesn't declare a type parameter, and so must already be in the scope of a generic type parameter `T` on the declaring class. But the question doesn't even mention that, so I don't get why you brought it up.

Comment: Oh, well, he asked what he was saying to the compiler with that line, so I thought it was relevant; plus he didn't accept the answer but that's probably just me reading into it wrong hoping to get my question answered. Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11304192/967873), that probably makes it more clear, if you have some classes that in its definition declares Generic parameter, you can write generic method like

```
public class SampleClass<T>{
  public static List<T> backwards (List<? super T> input)
}
```

otherwise, if your class doesn't declare generic parameter(or you want to define extra parameters), you should define your method in this way:

```
public class SampleClass{
    public static <T> List<T> backwards (List<? super T> input){...}
}
```

Comment: A very cool explanation!

Answer (score 2):

This is how you declare Generic Methods. Please read the following part and it will give you everything you need.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html